# How to show 3 components in react header? Seems like they are currently mutually exclusive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show 3 components in react header so that the UI will be like so: [image: React header UI]
The header should include 3 components which are (1) Cash balance: 123, (2) Asset balance: 123 and (3) the notification component as you can see on the right.
Additionally, (1) Cash balance: 123, (2) Asset balance: 123 should be in the middle of the header bar.

However, seems like the header can only show 1 component now, whenever I add a new component, for example,`<h5>Hi</h5>`to the header with the code like below:

```
return (
      <Fragment>
      <header className={classes.root}>
        <h5>Hi</h5>
      <HeaderNotification />
      </header>
      </Fragment>
  );
```

The notification will be gone, and shows this:[image: Error]
May I ask why would this happen and how could I show 3 components in react header?
Much appreciated.

To supplement, JSS styling for `root` is

```
root: {
    "position": "fixed",
      "top": "0",
      "left": "0",
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "6rem",
      "backgroundColor": "#8a2b06",
      "color": "white",
      "display": "flex",
      "justifyContent": "space-between",
      "alignItems": "center",
      "padding": "0 10%",
      "boxShadow": "0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
      "zIndex": "10",
      "margin": "0px 260px 0",
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked into the resulting HTML? Are the components still there, or are they not even present in the DOM?

Comment: Try applying styles to h5 so it shrinks to allow space for other components. https://css-tricks.com/understanding-flex-grow-flex-shrink-and-flex-basis/

Comment: What's going on in the `header` component itself?  Is it outputting all its child nodes, or is it something like the [react native](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/header/) header that's looking for specific child elements to display?

Comment: The width is set to 100%. However, you add padding on the left and right and a margin on the left that are unaccounted for. This is why the other elements go out of viewport. You should deduct these values from the width.

Answer (score 0):

The `HeaderNotification` is most likely present, but being pushed down by the `h5`-tag.

You could check this in the element inspector in your browser.

Try changing the width and height of the `h5`-tag and the `HeaderNotification`, or changing them to `display: inline`

```
return (
    <Fragment>
    <header className={classes.root}>
        <h5 style={{width: '10%'}}>Hi</h5>
        <HeaderNotification style={{width: '10%'}}/>
    </header>
    </Fragment>
);
```